# Error: Class "Zend_Locale_Data_Translation" not found in magento 2.4.6

Tags: magento2, magento2.4.6

I have recently upgrade magento version from 2.4.0 to 2.4.6 with. When i open configuration at time getting this error.

Answer (score 1):

Zend framework has been depreciated as of Magento 2.4.6

https://experienceleague.adobe.com/docs/commerce-operations/release/notes/magento-open-source/2-4-6.html?lang=en

It has been replaced with Laminas.

Answer (score 0):

This error occurs when Magento is unable to find the class "Zend_Locale_Data_Translation". This class is used by Magento to handle translation of date and time formats.

Here are a few steps you can try to resolve this error:

**1.Check if the file exists:**

Go to the root directory of your Magento installation and navigate to the following path:

```
vendor/zendframework/zend-i18n/src/Translator/Resources/languages/
```

Check if the file en/Zend_Locale_Data_Translation.php exists in this folder. If not, it could be a missing dependency issue.

**2.Update dependencies:**

Update the dependencies using the following command in your Magento root directory:

```
composer update
```

**3.Clear cache:**

Clear all Magento caches by running the following command in your Magento root directory:

```
php bin/magento cache:clean
```

**4.Check file permissions:**

Make sure that the file and folder permissions in your Magento installation are correct.

**5.Verify PHP version:**

Check if the PHP version installed on your server is compatible with Magento 2.4.6. Magento 2.4.6 requires PHP 8.1 or 8.2

**6.Reinstall Zend Framework:**

If the above steps do not resolve the issue, you can try reinstalling the Zend Framework by running the following command in your Magento root directory:

```
composer require zendframework/zend-i18n
```